# Работа с двумя txt файлами в Python

Tags: python, файлы, list

Есть два `.txt`-файла - в одном список e-mail'ов, в другом пароли от e-mail'ов. Изначально я использовал такой код, который выдает в случайном порядке пароль и e-mail:

```
email = open('emails.txt').read().split('\n')
password = open('passwords.txt').read().split('\n')

proxy = {'http': 'http://' + choice(proxies)}
useragent = {'User-Agent': choice(useragents)}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что если я беру email из списка `.txt`, стоящий по счету первым (`example@gogo.com`), то скрипт понимает, что нужно взять из файла с паролями тоже первый элемент (`qwerty`) и так по циклу до конца списка email'oв. А нужно, чтобы они шли все по порядку, а не случайным образом выбирались.

Answer (score 2):

Вот простой пример:

*emails.txt:*

```html
example@gogo.com
so_lover@stack.org
1337rep_bro@overflow.com
```

*passwords.txt:*

```html
qwerty123
Sh7jf990Fd__!*fh
love_stackoverflow
```

***Код:***

```py
with open('emails.txt') as f:
    emails = f.read().splitlines() 

with open('passwords.txt') as f:
    passwords = f.read().splitlines() 

res = dict(zip(emails, passwords))
print(res)
```

*stdout:*

```py
{'example@gogo.com': 'qwerty123', 'so_lover@stack.org': 'Sh7jf990Fd__!*fh', '1337rep_bro@overflow.com': 'love_stackoverflow'}
```